# An alarm type of circuit

Tags: digital-logic, nand

Scenario question1: An automobile manufacturer needs a logic circuit to perform a specific task in its new line of cars. These cars will be equipped with a “headlight left on” alarm that sounds any time these two conditions are met: headlights on and ignition switch off. Draw the schematic diagram of a logic gate circuit that will implement this alarm, constructed entirely out of NAND gates.

Comment: What have you done to try and solve this? Please show your working and also add a valid question into your post.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it’s a homework/test question with no effort made to try to solve it.

Comment: C'mon now, your instructor is not expecting much.  Two inputs to produce one output.